# ScrollIntoView and href working in IOS and PC but not in Android

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a restaurant menu component in reactjs and this menu render a "categories" component that is a horizontal structure of buttons and when i click in a button it should scroll the page to the similar categorie section. It works in IOS and in laptop, but it isnt working in android devices.

That is the component call in the menu:

```
 <div id="horizontalScroll" ref={horizontalScrollRef} className='mb-4 pt-1' >
                    {
                        categorias.map(categorias => {
                            return <Categorias 
                                    key={categorias.cat_id}
                                    cat_foto={categorias.cat_foto}
                                    cat_descricao={categorias.cat_descricao}
                                    cat_id={categorias.cat_id}/>
                        })
                    }
            </div>
```

And the component "categories" below:

```
import './categorias.css';
// import './script.js';
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

function Categorias(props){
    useEffect(() =>{
        let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

        buttons.forEach(button =>{
            button.addEventListener('click',function(){
                buttons.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
                this.classList.add('active');
            });
        });
    });

    function scrollToCategory(categoryId){
        const categoryElement = document.getElementById(categoryId);
        if(categoryElement){
            categoryElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'});
        }
    }


    return <>
        <div className='categorias me-2'>
            <div className='itens-categorias'>
                {/* tag a originalmente dentro da tag button, agora invertida */}
                <a className="" aria-current = "page" href={`#${props.cat_descricao}`}><button onClick={() => scrollToCategory(props.cat_descricao)} id="button-categoria" type="button">{props.cat_descricao}</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
}    

export default Categorias;
```

Does anyone know if there is a web-kit, function, query, media or anything similar that could help to scroll it in android?

Thank you!

I tried to use a scrollIntoView function with the behavior: smooth but it also didnt work

PS: some words like "categorias" are in portuguese, my original language< so there is no conflict with the words, cause an error would appear if it was the problem.

EDIT:
I have an useEffect that makes the horizontal bar scroll automatically and when i delete it the href works in android, dont know why.I need that useEffect too, wish the scroll to section and the useEffect worked together:

```
const horizontalScrollRef = useRef(null);


// Código para rolar automaticamente o scrollhorizontal ao abrir a página
useEffect(() => {
   
    if (horizontalScrollRef.current) {
    const scrollContainer = horizontalScrollRef.current;
    const scrollAmount = 1; //Velocidade do scroll

    //Direção do scroll 
    const scroll = () => {
        scrollContainer.scrollLeft += scrollAmount; 
    };

    //Intervalo
    const scrollInterval = setInterval(scroll, 50); 

    //Limpa o intervalo quando o componente for desmontado
    return () => clearInterval(scrollInterval);
    }
}, [horizontalScrollRef]);
```